# Remove referenced document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've successfully removed the subdocument of the parent using $pull. 
Now, how would I delete the subdocument in its own schema? 
Im sorry if it doesn't make any sense, node.js newb here. :)

UserSchema

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
   posts:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'post'}]
});
```

PostSchema

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
   user:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'user'}
});
```

Deletion:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, 
   {$pull:{'posts':post_id}},function(err,model){
      if(!err){
         console.log(model);
         resolve(model);
      }
      else{
        reject(err);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try create nested calls to remove the child schema as follows:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, 
   {$pull:{'posts':post_id}},function(err,model){
      if(!err){
         Post.find({ user : model._id }).remove().exec();
         console.log(model);
         resolve(model);
      }
      else{
        reject(err);
      }
});
```